# How to solve optimal control problem with reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The problem I am trying to attack is a predator-prey pursuit problem. There are multiple predators that pursue multiple preys and preys tried to evade predators. I am trying to solve a simplified version - one predator tries to catch a static prey on a plane. There is bunch of literature on the above problem when predators and preys are on the grid.

Can anybody suggest articles/code where such problem is solved on a continuous plane? I am looking at continuous state space, discrete action space (predator can turn left 10 degrees, go straight, turn right 10 degrees, runs at constant speed), and discrete time. MountainCar is one dimensional version (car is predator and flag is prey) and DQN works fine. However, when I tried DQN on two dimensional plane the training become very slow (I guess dimensionality curse).

The second question concerns the definition of states and reward. In my case I consider angle between predator heading vector and vector between the predator and prey positions. Reward is the change in distance between predator and prey, 10 when prey is captured, and -10 when predator gets too far from the prey. Is this reasonable? I already asked similar question before and with the help of @Neil Slater was able to refine reward and state.

The third question concerns when to update train network to target network. At each episode? Or only when prey is caught? Any ideas?

The last question I have is about the network structure: activation functions and regularization. Currently I am using two tanh hidden layers and linear output with l2 and dropout. Can anybody share some insights?

Thanks in advance!